# Import From LinkedIn Doesn't Bring Descriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linkedin

I just imported my LinkedIn work history into Careers 2.0 and all of my history was listed correctly on the import page (the page with "import this"/"update this" buttons) with titles, dates and descriptions but after importing the descriptions were lost (titles and dates came across).

EDIT: I've had this confirmed by another user as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed, thanks for the heads-up.